# What Visual Studio 2013 project files should be checked into source control?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a git repository of a Studio project and want to know what generated files from Studio 2013 should be checked in.  It's obvious that the .sln and .vcxproj should be checked in, but should the .v12.suo, .filters, and .sdf files be checked in also?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The `.suo` files are [Solution User Options files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx) and should not be checked into version control.

The `.sdf` file is a code-browsing database file that is generated by Visual Studio. It should not be checked into version control. [more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx0cxhaw.aspx)

The `.filters` files tell Visual Studio where in the solution to show your source code (for example, `.h` shows up in Header Files). Put these in version control. See first link for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Git in Visual Studio, you should set up the [Visual Studio .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) in your repository.  This will make sure that you're not adding anything user-specific to your repository, and it will future-proof you, as it contains paths that are user-specific for Visual Studio 2015 and even "Dev 15".

Comment: Thanks!  Does this only work if you are using git from Visual Studio?  Does the bash git shell recognize that those files should not be added too!

Comment: It will - once you set up the `.gitignore` it will be shared by all Git clients:  the command-line, Visual Studio and other tools.